# PyQt define maxlength of a label

Tags: pyqt, maxlength

How to set the maxlength of a Label in PyQt4?

> self.ui.labelxyz.maxlength(15)
>   Isn't the correct command for this.

Kind regards;

Comment: Do you mean the max chars contained in your QLabel?...

Answer (score 0):

you can check maximum length with `self.ui.labelxyz.maximumWidth()` or set it like this: `self.ui.labelxyz.setMaximumWidth(15)`

> maximumWidth : int
>
> This property holds the widget's maximum width in
> pixels. This property corresponds to the width held by the maximumSize
> property. By default, this property contains a value of 16777215.
>
> Access functions: int maximumWidth () const
>
> void setMaximumWidth ( int
> maxw )